# Google App Engine (Java) - Redirection to jsp from web.xml

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web.xml

I have problems whit redirections and Servlets in Google App Engine.
I have an index.jsp and a list.jsp, but I can't get the results expected.

I have this in web.xml:

```
<filter-name>URIParserFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.bbva.icaro2.web.filters.URIParserFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EntitiesAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproject.web.EntitiesAdminServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ListServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.myproject.web.ListServlet</servlet-class>
    <jsp-files>/lists/lists.jsp</jsp-files>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EntitiesAdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/entities/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/lists/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I access to http://myproject/lists/mylist
The thread goes to URIParserFilter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String entityKind = null;
    String id = null;
    String pathInfo = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getPathInfo();
    String pathString = (pathInfo == null || pathInfo.equals("/")) ? "" : pathInfo.substring(1);
    String[] parts = pathString.split("/");

    entityKind = parts[0].trim();
    id = (parts.length > 1) ? parts[1].trim() : null;

    req.setAttribute(Constants.REQ_ATTR_REQ_ENTITYKIND, entityKind); // entityKind = "mylist"
    req.setAttribute(Constants.REQ_ATTR_REQ_ENTITYID, id);

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
}
```

And then it goes to list.jsp whitout pass through ListServlet :-(
In case of http://myproject/admin/entities/hello it works!

The classes are exactly the same...

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1):

write the only  `<jsp-files>` with url pattern.it will redirect to jsp file.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.uks.MyServlet</servlet-class>
<jsp-files>/jsp/my.jsp</jsp-files>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: IThanks for your answer, it redirects to my jsp "lists.jsp" but the thread doesn't pass through my servlet: ListServlet

Comment: then you want to redirect inside the servlet code using RequestDispatcher.

Comment: But... It goes from URIParserFilter.doFilter() directly to "lists.jsp", how can I force it to pass through my servlet to redirect it?
I think I hace something wrong in my web.xml but I don't know what

Answer (score 0):

Do a forward from your servlet to your jsp page. Don't map the jsp in web.xml.

So do whatever you need to in your servlet and then:

```
String destination = "/jsp/my.jsp";
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(destination);
rd.forward(request, response);
```